# Create two semi-independent lists of material, which share their counter

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, tocloft

I successfully used `\newlistof{listofA}{A}{List of As}` and `\newlistentry{mycounter}{A}{0}` to create a list of A, whose contents gets added using `\addcontentsline{A}{mycounter}{\protect\numberline{\themycounter}...}`.
Now I want to have a list of B's that shares the counter `mycounter`.
I have `\newlistof{listofB}{B}{List of Bs}`.
`\newlistentry{mycounter}{B}{0}` fails with a few `Command ... already defined`. Without it, using `\addcontentsline{B}{mycounter}{...}`,
*both* lists turn out empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you, instead of providin a recipe with sie notes, just add a minimal working example, that we can copy/paste and compile and directly see the issue you see?

Comment: I guess I should.

Comment: Because, the minimal non-working example does actually work! My bad. I'll delete in a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

With the `xassoccnt` package it is possible to couple multiple counters, i.e. if one of the counters is stepped, to other ones are stepped too.

Declare a counters group with some 'arbitrary' name and assign the relevant counters to them.

Using the same counter is not possible since `\newlistof` expects a non-existing counter, say, `foo` and generates a bunch of commands out of the counter name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\newcommand{\listoffooname}{List of foo environments}
\newcommand{\listoffoobarname}{List of foobar environments}

\newlistof[section]{foo}{foo}{\listoffooname}
\newlistof[section]{foobar}{foobar}{\listoffoobarname}

\DeclareCoupledCountersGroup{foofoobar}
\DeclareCoupledCounters[name=foofoobar]{foo,foobar}


% Dummy usage of the counter and generating a 'ToC' entry
\newenvironment{foo}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{foo}
  \par\noindent\textbf{Foo \thefoo. #1}
  \addcontentsline{foo}{foo}{\protect\numberline{\thefoo} #1}\par%
}{\hrule}

\newenvironment{foobar}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{foobar}
  \par\noindent\textbf{Foobar \thefoobar. #1}
  \addcontentsline{foobar}{foobar}{\protect\numberline{\thefoobar} #1}\par%
}{\hrule}



\begin{document}
\listoffoo
\listoffoobar


\section{Where foo starts}

\begin{foo}{A nice foo}

\blindtext[2]
\end{foo}

\begin{foobar}{A nice foobar}

\blindtext[2]
\end{foobar}


\begin{foo}{A nice foo again}

\blindtext[2]
\end{foo}

\begin{foo}{A nice foo again}

\blindtext[2]
\end{foo}

\begin{foobar}{A nice foobar again}

\blindtext[2]
\end{foobar}




\section{Where foo ends}

\begin{foo}{Another nice foo too}

\blindtext[1]
\end{foo}

\begin{foobar}{Another nice foobar}

\blindtext[2]
\end{foobar}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another, 'quicker' method `\let\c@foobar\c@foo`